# Recuperar input dinâmico e inserir no banco com procedure

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou com problema para inserir dados recebidos de um input dinâmico. Minha procedure só insere uma vez, segue o meu código onde recebo os dados:

```
   $ddd     = $_POST['ddd'];
   $userid  = $_POST['userid'];
   $idusuario = $_POST['idusuario'];
   $telefone    = $_POST['telefone'];
   $obs         = $_POST['obs'];
   $quant_linhas = count($ddd);

   for ($i=0; $i<$quant_linhas; $i++) {

        $sql = "Call telefone_i(
        '".$userid[$i]."',
        '".$ddd[$i]."',
        '".$telefone[$i]."',
        '".$obs[$i]."',
        '".$idusuario[$i]."'

         )";

   }
```

Neste trecho encontra-se o jQuery que cria os inputs dinâmicos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});

</script>
```

Segue o trecho referentes aos inputs:

```
<div class="content" style="min-height: 150px;">
   <!-- CONTEUDO INICIO -->
    <center>
        <h2  style="background-color: #DDEBFF">Cadastrar Telefone</h2>
    </center>
    <div style=" margin-left:5px; padding: 5px; width: 600px; overflow:auto; border:#036 thin; border-style:dotted;">

<form action="telefone_inserir.php?id=<?php echo $usuario_id; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="list">
    <thead>
        <tr class="linhas">

            <td width="25%" class="right">DDD</td>

            <td class="left">

            <input type="text" name="ddd[]" value="" maxlength="2" style="width: 30px" />

            <input name="userid[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

            <input name="idusuario[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $usuario_id; ?>" />

            </td>

            <td width="25%" class="right">Telefone</td>

            <td class="left"><input type="text" name="telefone[]" value="" maxlength="9" style="width: 80px" /></td>

            <td width="25%" class="right">OBS:</td>

            <td class="left"><input type="text" name="obs[]" value="" maxlength="45" style="width: 200px" /></td>
            <td class="left"><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="imagens/exc_btn.png" border="0" /></a></td>

        </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="7">
        <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="imagens/tel_btn.png" border="0" /></a>
    </td></tr>

         <tr>

            <td colspan="7" align="center" height="50">
                <input name="botao" type="image" value="Alterar" id="btn_salvar" src="imagens/cadastrar_btn.png">

            </td>
          </tr>


          </thead>
        </table>

    </form>

    </div>
<!-- CONTEUDO FIM -->
</div>
```

Minha procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `telefone_i`(
p_usuario_id int(11) ,
p_ddd int(3) ,
p_telefone int(9) ,
p_obs varchar(45) ,
p_usuario_lancamento int(11)
)
BEGIN

insert acad.telefone
    set
        usuario_id = p_usuario_id,
        ddd = p_ddd,
        telefone = p_telefone,
        obs = p_obs,
        data_lancamento = current_timestamp,
        usuario_lancamento = p_usuario_lancamento;
END
```

Tentei fazer desta maneira tbm mais não deu certo:

```
   for ($i=0; $i<$quant_linhas; $i++) {

        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "Call telefone_i(
        '".$userid[$i]."',
        '".$ddd[$i]."',
        '".$telefone[$i]."',
        '".$obs[$i]."',
        '".$idusuario[$i]."'

         )");



   }
```

Mas minha procedure insere apenas 1 registro e retorna o erro "Query was empty". Tentei de outra maneira, mas acontece o mesmo efeito, apenas insere uma linha e retorna erro. Segue o trecho de código:

```
$msg =   mysql_query("Call telefone_i(
'".$userid[$i]."',
'".$ddd[$i]."',
'".$telefone[$i]."',
'".$obs[$i]."',
'".$idusuario[$i]."'

 )");
```

Desde já, agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Sua variável $id é um array?

Comment: não os inputs são criados dinamicamente com jquery o $id é para contar os números de inputs que são enviados

Comment: Isso entendi... Mas qual o tipo de dado vem nele? Um array, uma string separada por vírgula?

Comment: @MarceloBonus opa estava errado no lugar do $id era $ddd e vem num array sim

Comment: Como que alguém com 27 pontos oferece uma recompensa de 50 ?

Comment: @opeta, eu já coloquei uma resposta a sua pergunta, se ela atender à sua pergunta, marque-a como aceita. Obrigado.

Comment: @TaoPaiPai simples eu estava com 77 quando vc oferece a recompensa ela sai automáticamente dos seus pontos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema ao que tudo parece, é na maneira que está executando a submissão e na forma que está tentando inserir os dados no banco. Um detalhe importante que eu recomendo é remover a id da `querystring`, tanto por uma questão de segurança, como para não quebrar o loop nas suas IDs.

Se você precisa passar algo que não deve ser mostrado no seu POST, envie num input do tipo "hidden".

**OBS:** Fiquei meio confuso com as nomenclaturas porque você tem dois campos **userid** e **idusuario** mas entendi que um deles é o **usuario_lancamento**, eu sugiro alterar para que seu código fique mais claro, até para você mesmo:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','senha','acad');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Falha na conexão: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

if ($_POST) {
   if (count($_POST['telefone'])) {
      $i=0;
       foreach ($_POST['telefone'] as $telefone) {

           $data = array(
                         $_POST['userid'],
                         $_POST['ddd'][$i],
                         $telefone,
                         $_POST['obs'][$i],
                         $_POST['idusuario']
                   );

           $SQL = "CALL telefone_i('" . implode("','",$data) . "')";
           if ( ($result = $mysqli->query($SQL))===false ) {
                printf("Erro da Query: %s\nQuery enviada: %s\n",
                        $mysqli->error, $SQL);
                exit();
           } 
          $i++;   
       } //endforeach
   } 
}
```

Sua procedure deve ficar assim:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE acad$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS telefone_i$$

CREATE PROCEDURE telefone_i(
p_usuario_id int(11),
p_ddd int(3),
p_telefone int(9),
p_obs varchar(45),
p_usuario_lancamento int(11)
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO telefone (
  usuario_id,
  ddd, 
  telefone,
  obs,
  data_lancamento,
  usuario_lancamento
) VALUES (p_usuario_id,
         p_ddd,
         p_telefone,
         p_obs,
         now(),
         p_usuario_lancamento
);

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sua HTML deveria ficar assim:

```
<div class="content" style="min-height: 150px;">
   <!-- CONTEUDO INICIO -->
    <center>
        <h2  style="background-color: #DDEBFF">Cadastrar Telefone</h2>
    </center>
    <div style=" margin-left:5px; padding: 5px; width: 600px; overflow:auto; border:#036 thin; border-style:dotted;">
    <form action="telefone_inserir.php" method="post" id="insercao_tel">
        <table class="list">
           <thead>
                 <tr class="linhas">
                   <td width="25%" class="right">DDD</td>
                   <td class="left">
                      <input type="text" name="ddd[]" maxlength="2" style="width: 30px" />
                   </td>
                   <td width="25%" class="right">Telefone</td>
                   <td class="left">
                      <input type="text" name="telefone[]" maxlength="9" style="width: 80px" />
                   </td>
                   <td width="25%" class="right">OBS:</td>
                   <td class="left">
                      <input type="text" name="obs[]" maxlength="45" style="width: 200px" />
                  </td>
                  <td class="left">
                      <a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="imagens/exc_btn.png" border="0" /></a>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="7">
                      <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="imagens/tel_btn.png" border="0" /></a>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="7" align="center" height="50">
                     <input name="userid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                     <input name="idusuario" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $usuario_id; ?>" />
                     <input name="botao" type="image" value="Alterar" id="btn_salvar" src="imagens/cadastrar_btn.png">
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </thead>
       </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    <!-- CONTEUDO FIM -->
</div>
```

Comment: veja se tem um post 'ddd' sendo enviado. Tenta lá denovo.

Comment: ok, eu editei, veja lá... só um detalhe. Seu formulário não deve passar a id, no action.

Comment: Sua procedure espera um inteiro, não um valor nulo. Veja que no seu post, $user_id deve conter um valor. na saída da procedure eles não estão lá, nenhuma das IDs: p_usuario_id e p_usuario_lancamento ..., ou seja, quando vc criou os campos com o click, faltou alimentá-los com os values.

Comment: Mas pelo que estou vendo no seu código, quando vc duplica os campos, vc não está duplicando todos, só parte deles, isso que está errado... vc tem que fazer o foreach nos campos que serão duplicados. Se os dois ids não vão ser duplicados, não tem porque colocar como array `[]`.

Comment: Editei, veja lá se resolveu o problema.

Comment: Porque tem `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ? Isso é só para upload.

Comment: eu removi esse enctype="multipart/form-data cara deu certo eu te agradeço muito pela sua ajuda acho que foi os 50 pontos mais suados da sua vida kkkkkkk abraço até a próx.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Seu `insert` na Stored Procedure não está errado ?

Ele está como se fosse um `update`.

`INSERT` é assim:

`INSERT INTO TABELA (CAMPO_1, CAMPO_2) VALUES (VALOR_1, VALOR_2)`

Então, na sua SP seria assim:

```
insert into acad.telefone
(
    usuario_id, ddd, telefone, obs, data_lancamento, usuario_lancamento
)
values
(
   p_usuario_id,
   p_ddd,
   p_telefone,
   p_obs,
   current_timestamp,
   p_usuario_lancamento
)
```

Comment: realmente estava incorreta e já foi modificada

Answer (score 0):

Não a necessidade de criar uma procedure para fazer esse insert, e neste caso você também está perdendo performace, pois está abrindo várias transações no banco de dados.

A melhor maneira de fazer e fazendo um *INSERT* da seguinte maneira.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (3,4);
```

Então utilize o seguinte código:

```
$sql = "insert into acad.telefone (usuario_id, ddd, telefone, obs, data_lancamento, usuario_lancamento) VALUES ";

for ($i=0; $i<$quant_linhas; $i++) {
    $sql .= "(". '".$userid[$i]."' . "," . '".$ddd[$i]."' . "," . '".$telefone[$i]."' . "," . '".$obs[$i]."' . "," . '".$idusuario[$i]."' . ") "
}
```

Comment: infelizmente tenho que seguir as procedures

Answer (score 0):

A tua `procedure` está errada, para inserir valores através de uma procedure, deves fazer algo assim:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _nome(...)
BEGIN 
     INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE
     INTO   | SET    | FIELD
     VALUES | WHERE  | WHERE
     ...
END
```

Veja o exemplo:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE telefone_i(
                            p_usuario_id INT(11),
                            p_ddd INT(3),
                            p_telefone INT(9),
                            p_obs VARCHAR(45),
                            p_usuario_lancamento INT(11)
                            )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO acad.telefone (
            usuario_id,
            ddd,
            telefone,
            obs,
            data_lancamento,
            usuario_lancamento
        )   
        VALUES (
            p_usuario_id,
            p_ddd,
            p_telefone,
            p_obs,
            p_data_lancamento,
            p_usuario_lancamento
        );
    END //
```

No script `php` podes simplesmente fazer isto:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $i=0;
    foreach($_POST as $nome){
        $procedure = "CALL telefone_i({$_POST['userid'][$i]}, {$_POST['ddd'][$i]}, {$_POST['telefone'][$i]}, '{$_POST['obs'][$i]}', {$_POST['idusuario'][$i]})";
        if(!($query = $con->query($procedure))){
            die($con->error);
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Dentro desse loop, lidas com os valores enviados à partir do formulário , podendo verificar, e por aí.

Comment: ela insere somente a primeira e dá esse erro "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 21, 964071201, 'celular', )' at line 1"